# Is there a good tutorial(windows) for using openstreetmap planet.osm hourly/diff to update local postgres/postgis database?

Tags: postgresql, diff, openstreetmap, changeset

The purpose of this app is to get user statistics (like no. of ways 'amenity=school' created by a user).

Previously I tried changesetsGet and changesetDownload form osm api v0.6 for query. It took more than 1 minute for a single user. It must be a bad way to query main api.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the main API is quite slow and not suited for heavy queries.

Take a look at [switch2osm](http://switch2osm.org/) for a [manual on how to set up your own OSM database](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-12-04/). Just skip the parts for the tile server. The manual is for Linux though.

Comment: Thank U!. I am following the tutorial. The app I want is similar to one written by Zverik,[ https://github.com/Zverik/whodidit ]